# VBA: Change Excel cell width

Tags: excel, vba

I have some VBA and batch Scripts that read the Mac Address Table out of some switches and import it into Excel to format it.
But the text is too long for the default cell width.
Is it possible to change the displayed cell width?

(When saying displayed cell width I mean: [this](http://0.tqn.com/d/spreadsheets/1/0/r/1/-/-/col_width1.gif))

Comment: The given link is dead / gives an Access Denied error. It is also [not archived](https://web.archive.org/web/*/http://0.tqn.com/d/spreadsheets/1/0/r/1/-/-/col_width1.gif). Maybe the OP still has access. Such old questions still have an audience.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not, but the accepted answer should make it clear enough.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use this:

```
Range("A1").ColumnWidth = ...
```

The units for this value are as following:

> One unit of column width is equal to the width of one character in the Normal style. For proportional fonts, the width of the character 0 (zero) is used.

For example, the column width for freshly opened Excel file with default styles is `8.43` which is equal to 64 pixels.

...or this to autofit width:

```
Range("A1").EntireColumn.AutoFit
```

Comment: Thank you, it Works, but what does `ColumnWidth = ...` the value mean, you put in instead of "..."? Is it in Pixel?

Comment: Thank you for sharing the AutoFit!

Answer (score 6):

Another method would be:

```
.Columns("A").ColumnWidth = 20 (or whatever value you need)
```

I didn't compare it speedwise but why my guess would be that it's more efficient to just use Columns() instead of Range().

For more info on the ColumnWidth-Value -> [MSDN Doc for the columnwidth-property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-columnwidth-property-excel)